# Prevent resizing browser from changing HTML/CSS layout

Tags: html, css, browser, resize

I have the following code for an animation in CSS and HTML:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Animation/LipstickAd</title>

  <link rel= "stylesheet" href = "style.css"></a>



  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="logos" class = "main1">
      <img src="moveable_part.png" height="750px" class="center"></img>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
          <img id="lipstick_ad" src="lipstick_ad.png" height="750px" class="center"></img>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

where style.css has:

```
#logos{
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 2s infinite;

}

    @-webkit-keyframes mymove {

      0%{
        top:80px;
        opacity:0%;
        /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; */

      }

      50%{
        opacity:100%;
        top:50px;
        /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; */
      }

      100%{
        top:80px;
      }


    }


    .center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.main1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  right: -285px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

This works great in full screen (I found out the right px to use by trial and error), but as soon as I resize the browser, the position of the elements in main1 (the top of the lipstick change) and it looks terrible.

How can I prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of Metatag Viewport is to get responsiveness on Webpage, to Prevent default responsiveness on resize just remove it.
Use below HTML, or Remove viewport meta line from your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Animation/LipstickAd</title>

  <link rel= "stylesheet" href = "style.css"></a>



  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="logos" class = "main1">
      <img src="moveable_part.png" height="750px" class="center"></img>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
          <img id="lipstick_ad" src="lipstick_ad.png" height="750px" class="center"></img>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain your answer, don't just provide code. What does your change do?

Comment: @Zombie_Pigdragon thanks, i edited my answer with explanation.

Comment: hmm thanks for the answer but this didn't seem to work